# voice recognition for Android application

Tags: android, voice-recognition

I want to develop an Android application for learning English and I would like it to have a voice recognition feature as part of the exercises in the application.

Is there anything ready which I can add to my application to implement it ? Do you have any suggestions from where to start ? And is it too complicated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you consider about [SpeechRecognizer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html). This class provides access to the speech recognition service. This service allows access to the speech recognizer. Do not instantiate this class directly, instead, call [createSpeechRecognizer(Context)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html#createSpeechRecognizer%28android.content.Context%29). This class's methods must be invoked only from the main application thread.

I hope this will help you.